# SharedPreferences in non activity class NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to use `SharedPreferences` in a non `activity` class from `onResume()` in an activity but I'm getting a NullPointerException on the `context`.

For some reason I cannot get the `context` in `onResume()`. Not sure if I'm missing something, but any help would be appreciated.

**onResume() Method in my activity**

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // The activity has become visible (it is now "resumed").

    // Check User's Access Token exists and hasn't expired.
    AccountFunctions accountFunctions = new AccountFunctions();

    if (!accountFunctions.validateUserToken(this)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**validateUserToken(Context context) method in AccountFunctions Class**

```
public Boolean validateUserToken(Context context) {

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.user_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE); // This is where the error is thrown
    String accessToken = sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.user_access_token), null);
    DateTime expiryDate = new DateTime(sharedPref.getLong(getString(R.string.user_expires), 0));

    if (accessToken == null || expiryDate.isBeforeNow()) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**The Error**

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity 
>   {uk.co.itsstonbury.www.intouch/uk.co.itsstonbury.www.intouch.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.Context
>   android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object
>   reference

Comment: Your issue is that `AccountFunctions` appears to extend some `Context` or `Activity` class, and it really shouldn't.

Comment: I wouldn't consider this a duplicate of the one linked. My question is to do with a problem with the context as solved by the answer below. Don't think it warrants a down vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace `getString(R.str` with `context.getString` because `AccountFunctions` class has not been created by the OS so it doesn't have it's own context ready.

Basically activity gets it's context form application when `oncreate` function get called by OS callbacks since it's not gonna happen in this case so `AccountFunctions` object will not have it's own context

This code simply assume that `AccountFunctions` will be created normally through `intent` but in this case it is like a simple class object which has no connection with activity life-cycle calls.

so your code will look like

```
public Boolean validateUserToken(Context context) {

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getString(R.string.user_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE); // This is where the error is thrown
    String accessToken = sharedPref.getString(context.getString(R.string.user_access_token), null);
    DateTime expiryDate = new DateTime(sharedPref.getLong(context.getString(R.string.user_expires), 0));

    if (accessToken == null || expiryDate.isBeforeNow()) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

or you can use string values directly

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("yourkey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); // This is where the error is thrown
```

or

The better option is create a separate Util class for helper function rather like

```
class Util{

    public static boolean validateUserToken(Context context) {

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getString(R.string.user_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE); // This is where the error is thrown
        String accessToken = sharedPref.getString(context.getString(context.R.string.user_access_token), null);
        DateTime expiryDate = new DateTime(sharedPref.getLong(context.getString(R.string.user_expires), 0));

        if (accessToken == null || expiryDate.isBeforeNow()) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

from your activity call it like

```
 Util.validateUserToken(this);
```

Comment: @cricket_007 this `getString(context.R.s` will try to find and use the `AccountFunctions` activity context which is not there because OP just created the object

Comment: Yeah, I commented above. `getString` shouldn't even be a directly accessible method of that class

Comment: @cricket_007 since `AccountFunctions` is an activity so subtle issue in this case :P

Comment: I'm just saying that it appears to be a static helper / utility class. If it did extend `Activity`, then it doesn't need to. And if it didn't, then `getString` isn't an available method

Comment: @cricket_007 i know and yeah it could be a helper class , but we can't see what else is there

Comment: Great answer, thank you. Yes it is a helper class but I was extending Application which was my problem and changing to `context.getstring` it now works as expected.

Comment: @RichardMcKenna i am glad i could help and thank you for the compliment  :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.user_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` 

with
`SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getString(R.string.user_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`