# Get SharedPreferences from non extended class

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm Trying to get my sql server information from SharedPreferences but cant seem to get it working in me connectioclass if i would do the same in een extended class it would work but for this code i dont want a extended class:

Normaly i use:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
```

so i tryed:

```
Context context = this;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

and:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

But not working

Thi is my code:

```
public class ConnectionClass{

PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String servername = sharedPreferences.getString("SQLSERVER", "");
String databasenaam = sharedPreferences.getString("SQLDATABASE", "");
String serverusernaam = sharedPreferences.getString("SQLUSERNAAM", "");
String serverpassword = sharedPreferences.getString("SQLPASSWORD", "");

String ip = servername;
String classs = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
String db = databasenaam ;
String un = serverusernaam;
String password = serverpassword ;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public Connection CONN() {

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    Connection conn = null;
    String ConnURL = null;
    try {

        Class.forName(classs);
        ConnURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip + ";"
                + "databaseName=" + db + ";user=" + un + ";password="
                + password + ";";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        Log.e("ERRO", se.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
    }
    return conn;
}

}
```

Comment: you can try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40894989/sharedpreferences-in-non-activity-class-nullpointerexception/40895108#40895108

Comment: pass the context from the calling Activity

Comment: Or simply retrieve the user id and password from the SharedPreferences in your main Activity and then pass them to the "non extended class" method which retrieves the data.

Comment: @user2433624 if my answer helped you, please accept it and maybe vote it upt :)

Answer (score 0):

Since `getDefaultSharedPreferencesName()` needs `Context` as argument, most classes not extending `Context` nor `Activity` (incl. subclasses) are out of luck while passing `this` as argument. This shall now be pretty clear why this happens and knowing that you know what would be proper substitutio: `Context` or subclasses. In you case I'd try to call `getApplicationContext()`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem arises because your class is custom and does not extend the `Context` class. The method `getDefaultSharedPreferences` takes a `Context` object as parameter.

You could do it like this:
The moment you create a `ConnectionClass` object pass the context of the `Activity` you are calling from to the constructor.

```
ConnectionClass c = new ConnectionClass(this); // this is instance of calling Activity
```

Then initialize the fields of your choice from SharedPreferences inside of your constructor.

```
public ConnectionClass(Context context) {
   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
   servername = sharedPreferences.getString("SQLSERVER", "");
   // ... and so on
}
```

Comment: @user2433624 please mark an answer and upvote if it helped you